# Convert python string into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am hoping someone could help me convert python string into numpy array. Essentially, given that I have a  Python string like this:

`'[ 0.11591    0.044932   0.66926   -0.67844    0.47253   -0.84737\n  1.0734    -0.075396  -0.22688    0.84021   -0.46608    0.019941\n -0.0020394 -0.13038    0.8911    -0.40015    0.52048    0.69283\n -0.10257    0.54296   -0.416      0.36585    0.96078    0.50816\n  0.50144    0.66489   -0.79224    0.44567    0.90822   -0.67522\n  0.047322   0.48399   -0.53316    0.76157   -0.86072    0.091377\n  0.30159   -1.194      0.8679    -0.58691    0.48712   -0.66167\n -0.24265   -0.18849   -0.19353    0.0014832  0.88768    0.36672\n  0.16211    0.56235  ]'`

I want to convert it into a 1x50 dimensional array in Python. Is there any efficient way of doing it? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: How I get that string? It is initially a numpy array as a value in a dictionary. Then I save that into the database with the data type of `TEXT`. Afterward, I load the text that contains numpy array from the database.

Comment: Can you share how you've gotten that string? You can massage that to get it into numpy for sure but that's only going to be a kludge and I suspect there's much nicer ways depending how it was created/how you're retrieving it.

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html ?

Comment: Just update the way I retrieved the string and how it is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you have such a string:

```
line = '[ 0.11591    0.044932   0.66926   -0.67844    0.47253   -0.84737\n  1.0734    -0.075396  -0.22688    0.84021   -0.46608    0.019941\n -0.0020394 -0.13038    0.8911    -0.40015    0.52048    0.69283\n -0.10257    0.54296   -0.416      0.36585    0.96078    0.50816\n  0.50144    0.66489   -0.79224    0.44567    0.90822   -0.67522\n  0.047322   0.48399   -0.53316    0.76157   -0.86072    0.091377\n  0.30159   -1.194      0.8679    -0.58691    0.48712   -0.66167\n -0.24265   -0.18849   -0.19353    0.0014832  0.88768    0.36672\n  0.16211    0.56235  ]'
```

Just remove the first and the last element from it, split it and convert the elements to numbers:

```
map(float, line[1:-2].split())
```

Or just use the `numpy.fromstring` function:

```
numpy.fromstring(line[1:-2], dtype=float, sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to solve it:

```
import numpy as np
import re

txt = '[ 0.11591    0.044932   0.66926   -0.67844    0.47253   -0.84737\n  1.0734    -0.075396  -0.22688    0.84021   -0.46608    0.019941\n -0.0020394 -0.13038    0.8911    -0.40015    0.52048    0.69283\n -0.10257    0.54296   -0.416      0.36585    0.96078    0.50816\n  0.50144    0.66489   -0.79224    0.44567    0.90822   -0.67522\n  0.047322   0.48399   -0.53316    0.76157   -0.86072    0.091377\n  0.30159   -1.194      0.8679    -0.58691    0.48712   -0.66167\n -0.24265   -0.18849   -0.19353    0.0014832  0.88768    0.36672\n  0.16211    0.56235  ]'

txt = re.sub(r'\n','', txt)
myList = txt.split()[1:-1]
myList2 = list(map(float,myList))
n_arr = np.array(myList)
print(n_arr)
```